# open file (e.g. right click/ open with) event for python3 script on a mac

Tags: python, pyqt

I would like my python3 script to react to an open file event. Is there any way to achieve that? The following python3 script is named `example`

```
#!/path/to/python3

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget

def window():
   app = QApplication(sys.argv)
   widget = QWidget()

   widget.setWindowTitle("Simple example")
   widget.show()
   sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
   window()
```

I generated the following directories to form a [bundle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bundle_(macOS)):

```
example.app/
-- Contents/
   -- Info.plist
   -- MacOS/
      -- example
```

The Info.plist file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>example</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

However, while I can execute it by, e.g., double clicking the .app file itself, I could not have it react to 'open file'.

The following apple script wrapper works, but is quite ugly:

```
on open theDroppedItems
    repeat with a from 1 to length of theDroppedItems
        set theCurrentDroppedItem to item a of theDroppedItems
        set posixfile to (POSIX path of theCurrentDroppedItem)
        # display dialog posixfile
        do shell script "/path/to/python3 /path/to/python3script " & posixfile
    end repeat
end open
```

It 'converts' open file to a command line argument. Supposedly, Qt [could work](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfileopenevent.html) and [Tk](https://%20https://github.com/roseman/idle/blob/master/macosxSupport.py) as well (l.90), but I could not find a simple example implementing it.

Comment: By "reacting to open file", do you mean someone pressing `Ctrl`+`O`, or by someone opening a file (say by double-clicking it in the file browser)?

Comment: Double clicking or a drag and drop.

Comment: @Andy the Qt documentation shows that you must override the [`event()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qapplication.html#event) of the QApplication. Did you create the bundle with the proper `plist` file?

Comment: I updated the question to include the information. Just to clarify again: I would like to either (1) double-click an associated file, (2) right click the same file and use open-with or (3) drag and drop on example.app. Then, the file should be accessible from the Qt code comparable to argv, argc at the command line.

Comment: You may want to have look at this: https://pythonhosted.org/watchdog/